# For Loop doesn´t print out correctly

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I created an for loop.

What do I have to do to print out: test0 test1 test2 test3

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        int x = 0;
        System.out.println("test"+x);
        x++;

    }
```

But it doesn´t print out: test0 test1 test2 test3

It prints out: 
test0
test0
test0
test0

Comment: replace `x` with `i` this should be `System.out.println("test"+i);` not `x`, `x` is always `0`

Comment: Thank u is there any possibility to handle it with x?

Comment: But I made x++;?

Comment: You again initialized the x=0

Comment: `int x = 0;` have this outside of loop @Marek, everytime `x` will be initialized to `0`

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just get rid of the two lines with `x` and just use `i` since this will give you the desired behavior without initializing an unnecessary variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change "x" to "i", because "i" is the index variable and is incremented by 1 each iteration. "x" is a local variable and will always be 0 because you redefine it each iteration. You could either do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("test" + i);
    x++;

}
```

Or this:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    System.out.println("test" + x);
    x++;

}
```

Comment: Declaring two variables when they're identical is pointless though. Also uses an unnecessary amount of memory (although it's not that much more, it can add up to a lot depending on how it's run). The first option is definitively the best

Comment: Yeah, I thought about editing it into my answer, but that would be pointless too, because I think he is not as advanced of a programmer yet to think about memory management ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are defining `x` in every iteration. Put `x` outside of the loop. Above it.

```
int x = 0
for (...) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("test"+i);
}
```

or // if you insist using x!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int x = i;
    System.out.println("test"+x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a very similar example in the [Oracle 'for Statement' documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

> The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of
>   values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the
>   way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is
>   satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as
>   follows:
>
> `for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>       statement(s) 
>   }`
>
> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed
>     once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to
>     false, the loop terminates.
> - ***The increment expression is invoked after
>     each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this
>     expression to increment or decrement a value.***

You need to declare `x` outside of the loop, otherwise it will be set to 0 after each iteration. So, in your case it will be:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("test" + x);
    x++;
}
```

For this example you don't need to declare two variables, you can get the same result by using the variable declared for the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("test" + i);
}
```

As this post has a lot of similar answers I will refer to another way of doing this particular loop taken from the [Oracle 'for Statement' documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), the 'enhanced for to loop through an array':

```
 int[] numbers = {0,1,2,3};
 for (int item : numbers) {
   System.out.println("test" + item);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use assignment operator `=` to assign value `0` to the `x`. Your variable `x` every time updated with **0**. So it prints out: test0 test0..... Because it is inside the for-loop.

If the variable `x` was declared outside of the for-loop that time `x` was not updated with `0`, it has just updated with `x=x+1` mean `++` operator. SO it will increment and worked perfectly. And one more thing, here `x` is a global variable for for-loop that can accessible inside the for-loop. Please see bellow code.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("test"+x);
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used x as your variable that prints out. You should consider the scope of the variable x. Every time the loop is run again x resets its value to 0 as it is declared inside the loop. Incrementing x at the end would not help you as the value of x is reset to 0 when the next iteration of the loop is run. Instead, replace x with **i** or declare a new variable outside the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("test" + i);
    x++;

}
```

or you can do

```
int a = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
System.out.println("test" + a);
a++;
}
```